# How would one create an algorithm class like the algorithm used to choose a random number in java?

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm not asking what the actually code is for the random number algorithm is, which I believe is PRNG, the psuedorandom number generator:

How is something like this random number algorithm generator code, would you use the same class structure for a concrete class in java like with instance variables, default constructors, overload constructors, getMethods, methods, toString, or would you code these algorithms a different way? In addition, I was also wondering if there were any specific programs that one could use to create an algorithm class?

NOTE: If you have any question, fell free to leave them in the comments before downvoting the question. Thank you all the help that I can get is greatly appreciated!

NOTE: Also, I know that there a lot of algorithms out there, but when I am looking for my answer, if we end up even needing an answer. It would be great if it could be for the Java algorithms or just the most common type of algorithms in general, not just some random ones. Thanks again!

Comment: I won't downvote, but your question seems a bit broad and amorphous.  Do you have a specific programming question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you, that is very nice of you, I guess, I could get a little more specific with the question. Just give me a few minute to edit it.

Comment: I won't downvote, but there are a lot algorithms about random out there.  It is not too hard to find.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen that is really the most specific I can make this question. I know that it is still a little broad, but please just answer to the best of your ability and knowledge, I sure that someone should be able to get a correct answer. If you have any ideas of how I could make the question a little more specific and coherent, then I am all ears

Comment: @javaLover Honestly, I know that it shouldn't be hard for me to find, but when I looked up the code for the API on Random for Java, I just could find the site. If you know of any place, I would certain just be able to go through it that way, and would then be happy to delete my question. Also, I know that there a lot of algorithms out there, but when I am looking for my answer, if we end up even needing an answer. It would be great if it could be for the Java algorithms or just the most common type of algorithms in general, not just some random ones. Thank you all!

Comment: `instance variables, default constructors, overload constructors, getMethods, methods, toString` - if you understand **why** and **when** you need those things, you should be able to figure out whether you need them in any given scenario, so you might be asking the wrong question. There are many possible structures for a PRNG class, it mostly comes down to how you want to use it. If you want a black-box PRNG (i.e. if external classes won't know or care much about the internal workings), get-methods and toString wouldn't make much sense IMO.